# Defining struct within typedef struct

Tags: c++, struct

```
typedef struct leaf{
  int value;
  struct leaf* lchild;
  struct leaf* rchild;
} LEAF;
```

For example the one above defines structure `leaf` and makes 2 members of that type: lchild, rchild. So is this like a recursion?

Comment: For some definition of "kinda", maybe... But, not really. You're not making members that have the same type as the struct, but members that are pointers to other objects having that struct as their type... So it's more of a "forward reference" kind of thing since the type isn't fully defined yet; not recursive...

Comment: There's no need in C++ for the `typedef ... LEAF` wrapper, nor for the two uses of `struct` inside the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. `leaf` has 2 members of type `leaf*`, not `leaf`. So it's not (data) recursion.

And the following

```
struct leaf
{
    leaf x;
};
```

would be illegal in C++. Note that in C++ you don't need `struct leaf` when you declare a member of variable of that type, nor do you need the `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a data structure that you would often want to process with a recursive algorithm. So yes I guess it's kind of like 'data recursion'.

Note that 'leaf' is a really bad name. By normal terminolgy a leaf has no children, 'node' or something like it would be the normal name.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) is:

> "...allowing a function to call itself..."

What you have there is just basically a reference(pointer) to another struct.

Assuming that you are working with binary trees an example of recursion would be the [inorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Inorder) search. Where the *inorder* method calls itself to the left child and the right child.

Comment: That's not the only definition of "recursion."

Comment: You are right it could be a recursive data type. I should have been more specific.