# Accessing a member of a pointer (variable) struct within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

Here's the deal: I am working on a C function that configures a struct that contains many members, as the *BASE (Pointer to a Struct),ID,MODE; but the BASE is a struct that might be defined as (say) "struct a", "struct b", "...", depending of the interface. This is the struct (and some examples) declaration:

```
typedef unsigned int u32_t;
typedef unsigned char u8_t;
typedef struct _interface_t{
    u32_t *BASE;
    u8_t ID;
    u32_t MODE;
} interface_t;

interface_t USART0_DEV  = {AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0}; // <-- Here we have a AT91C_BASE_US0 struct as *BASE
interface_t USART1_DEV  = {AT91C_BASE_US1, AT91C_ID_US1, 0};
interface_t TC0_DEV     = {AT91C_BASE_TC0, AT91C_ID_TC0, 0}; // <-- Here we have a AT91C_BASE_TC0 struct as *BASE
interface_t TC1_DEV     = {AT91C_BASE_TC1, AT91C_ID_TC1, 0};
interface_t TC2_DEV     = {AT91C_BASE_TC2, AT91C_ID_TC2, 0};
interface_t TWI_DEV     = {AT91C_BASE_TWI, AT91C_ID_TWI, 0}; // <-- Here we have a AT91C_BASE_TWI struct as *BASE
```

As you see I used `u32_t` instead of the struct because I'm declaring a pointer to that struct.  Later I have my function defined as:

```
unsigned char ConfigureDevice(interface_t *Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){
    ...
    Interface->BASE->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger; //Note: US_IER Must receive a vector to a function
    ...
}
```

But I get error 'US_IER could not be resolved'.
So I tried `AT91S_USART InterfaceBASE = Interface->BASE; InterfaceBASE->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger;` instead of `Interface->BASE->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger;` and got no error. But I can't use this, because I don't always know what kind of interface I'm handling (until I read ID member).

It gets even worst: When I try to compile I keep getting `conflicting type qualifiers for 'u32_t'` error in the `u32_t` typedef and `initialization from incompatible pointer type` and `near initialization for USART0_DEV.BASE` warnings in each of the `interface_t` definitions.

I searched in the forums but I couldn't figure my error(s) out. These ones kinda helped:

- [creating struct within struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800703/creating-struct-within-struct)
- [Defining struct within typedef struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181084/defining-struct-within-typedef-struct)

What's wrong with my code?
What can I do to use something like `Interface->BASE->US_IER`

**EDIT:** Hi!, so now this is what I got:

```
typedef struct _Interface_t{
    struct PERIPH_BASE * BASE;
    u32_t ID;
    u32_t MODE;
Interface_t;

Interface_t USART0_DEV  = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0};
...
unsigned char ConfigureDevice(Interface_t *Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger,...
...
((AT91S_SYS)Interface->BASE)->AIC_IECR = IRQ_Trigger; //No problems marked by Eclipse Code Editor
....
```

}

Looks Fine, but when compiling I get `cast to union type from type not present in union` Error...

Comment: Is `US_IER` always the first member of the struct `BASE` points to?

Comment: not always the first, but it is a member of every possible interface type

Comment: Then I am not sure you can make this work unless you can figure out which interface type it is supposed to be.

Comment: You're trying to lie to the compiler, and it doesn't like being lied to, so it gets its own back. This is normal; dishonesty doesn't pay, especially not in C code. You're trying to use the `BASE` to represent a generic pointer. In C, generic pointer is spelled `void *`. Whether changing BASE to `void *` (and consequential changes using casts when accessing data through BASE) is sufficient is open to debate. You might be better off with a union, or you might not. It might depend on whether you have an open-ended list of interface types. (Also, be cautious about using names starting with `_`.)

Comment: List is not Open-Ended, but it has ~128 Diferent Structure Types; I was trying to declare the 128 types with a case/switch, but I still get the `type qualifiers for 'u32_t'` error in the u32_t typedef and `initialization from incompatible pointer type` and `near initialization for USART0_DEV.BASE` warnings in each of the interface_t definitions, even after trying to cast the pointer to a u32_t*. I don't figure out another way of typedefing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BASE is a variable of type `u32_t pointer` and trying to access a member `US_IER` which is not really available in `u32_t pointer`. But your expectation of having this defined as a `u32_t pointer` instead `structure pointer` may not be possible as the compiler will expect a member should have been defined if it is accessed via a struct pointer.

But for your case(ie, having 128 different interface type), define a structure type with these 3 required members(common in all 128 interfaces) `US_IER, US_IAM, US_IDM` and define an union within that structure with required possible members and try accessing these items with a switch case or if else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay "open", you should either define your `BASE` as a

```
void *BASE;
```

or, in order to signal/document that it is a special pointer, you can use an incomplete type:

```
struct hwbase * BASE;
```

and define it as

```
interface_t USART0_DEV  = {AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0};
```

if you used `void *` or rather

```
interface_t USART0_DEV  = {(struct hwbase *)AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0};
```

for the 2nd option.

Then, upon using it, after you have made sure that you operate on the right type of hardware (e. g. TWI, USART), you can cast.

Cast your pointer from above to the right type, such as

```
unsigned char ConfigureDevice(interface_t *Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){
    ...
    ((AT91S_USART *)Interface->BASE)->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger; //Note: US_IER Must receive a vector to a function
    ...
}
```

(here I am not sure if `AT91S_USART` is already a pointer type - in this case, you omit the `*`.)

Another option could be to add some function pointers in order to have a kind of "poor man's OOP":

```
typedef void config_func(struct _interface_t *, whateveryouneed...)

config_func config_usart; // forward declaration, does as well ensire you have no typo in the function
typedef struct _interface_t{
    void *BASE;
    u8_t ID;
    u32_t MODE;
    config_func * configure; // function pointer
} interface_t;

interface_t USART0_DEV  = {AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0, config_usart };

void config_usart(struct _interface_t * iface, whateveryouneed...)
{
    AT91S_USART * my_base = iface->BASE;
    ...
    my_base->US_IER = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, It kinda worked this way; I got no warning in the Eclipse Code Editor, but Still Compiler Complains... `cast to union type from type not present in union`

Comment: Almost, indeed it was `(AT91S_USART *)Interface->USART_IER`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your base member as a pointer on a u32_t so the compiler think what is pointed by it is a u32_t and u32_t doesn't have a member named US_IER. 
What happen when you use the "working" version of you're code is a implicit cast of the pointer from uint_32* to AT91S_USART*, which contains the wanted member.

Comment: how can Declare that the pointer has the `US_IER`, `US_IAM`, `US_IDM`, ... Members? without declaring the Interface type. Should I use if/else if/else if... for the 128 Interface types?

Comment: Do they all contain different member ?

Comment: Yes, they're all different from each other, but they always contain at least those 3 members (US_IER, US_IAM, US_IDM)

Comment: One way i could see myself doing it is doing getter and setter for the  members that are shared by all Interface. That way you could kind of encapsulate the switch/case or if/else if.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? (getter and setter)

Comment: you'd could have something like 

`void setBase_USIER(Interface* interface, US_IER_T us_ier)

{
switch(interface->ID){
case AT91C_ID_US0:
AT91S_USART interfacebase = interface->Base;
interfacebase->US_IER = us_ier;
break;
//same thing for all other interface
}
}`

It is kind like using the object oriented paradigm.

Comment: Interesting ... Thanks!

How could I overcome the `type qualifiers for 'u32_t'` error in the u32_t typedef and `initialization from incompatible pointer type` and `near initialization for USART0_DEV.BASE warnings` in each of the interface_t definitions.

Comment: Seem like another type error to me, you could try casting your pointer to a u32_t*. Hovewer, i would like to mention to try to do it another way because it seem kinda bad to me.

Comment: I tried, but compiler still complains!; btw, I'm working in a case/switch, I think that even if it's a big block, solves my problems...