# Redefining a Declared (undefined?) Struct as Another Struct

Tags: c, struct

From this Question: "[Accessing a member of a pointer (variable) struct within a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094443/accessing-a-member-of-a-pointer-variable-struct-within-a-struct)". We could use an (undefined?) struct to accept some (unknown type?) parameters: The C function that configures a struct that contains many members, as the *BASE (Pointer to a Struct),ID,MODE; but the BASE is a struct that might be defined as (say) "struct a", "struct b", "...", depending of the interface. After discussion in the previous question, We finally arrived to this struct declaration:

```
typedef struct _Interface_t{
    struct PERIPH_BASE * BASE;
    u32_t ID;
    u32_t MODE;
} Interface_t;                                                         //Typo edit

interface_t USART0_DEV  = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0}; // <-- AT91C_BASE_US0 struct as *BASE
interface_t TC0_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TC0, AT91C_ID_TC0, 0}; // <-- AT91C_BASE_TC0 struct as *BASE
interface_t TWI_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TWI, AT91C_ID_TWI, 0}; // <-- AT91C_BASE_TWI struct as *BASE
...
unsigned char ConfigureDevice(Interface_t Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger, u32_t IRQ_Mode, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){
    ...
    USART_Configure(Interface, config, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK);         //ERROR0
    if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
        ((AT91S_USART)Interface->BASE)->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger;             //ERROR1
    }
    USART_SetTransmitterEnabled(Interface->BASE, 1);                      //ERROR1
    USART_SetReceiverEnabled(Interface->BASE, 1);                         //ERROR1
}
```

In this way Eclipse Code Editor Did not throw any warning or error, but the I Builded all project and Compiler Complained:

`incompatible type for argument 1 of 'USART_Configure'` (ERROR0)

`invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Interface_t')` (ERROR1)

Before I was recieving the following error: `"cast to union type from type not present in union"`;

So, I think that Maybe ater I know the Type of `BASE` Struct I'm "Recieving" (AT91S_PWMC, AT91S_USART, AT91S_AIC,... :Please Read [Accessing a member of a pointer (variable) struct within a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094443/accessing-a-member-of-a-pointer-variable-struct-within-a-struct)) I can (re)define the PERIPH_BASE Struct as been just as the Recieved Struct. Please Correct me if I'm Wrong...

Best Regards!, Thanks in advance for you answers!

**EDIT:** Adding USART_Configure code:

```
void USART_Configure(AT91S_USART *usart,
                            unsigned int mode,
                            unsigned int baudrate,
                            unsigned int masterClock)
{
    // Reset and disable receiver & transmitter
    usart->US_CR = AT91C_US_RSTRX | AT91C_US_RSTTX
                   | AT91C_US_RXDIS | AT91C_US_TXDIS;

    // Configure mode
    usart->US_MR = mode;

    // Configure baudrate
    // Asynchronous, no oversampling
    if (((mode & AT91C_US_SYNC) == 0)
        && ((mode & AT91C_US_OVER) == 0)) {

        usart->US_BRGR = (masterClock / baudrate) / 16;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Full Code

```
#include "Config_file.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "aic/aic.h"
#include "pmc/pmc.h"
#include "twi/twi.h"
#include "usart/usart.h"

typedef volatile unsigned int u32_t;
typedef struct _Interface_t{
    struct PERIPH_BASE * BASE;
    u32_t ID;
    u32_t MODE;
} Interface_t;

Interface_t USART0_DEV  = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_US0, AT91C_ID_US0, 0};
Interface_t USART1_DEV  = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_US1, AT91C_ID_US1, 0};
Interface_t TC0_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TC0, AT91C_ID_TC0, 0};
Interface_t TC1_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TC1, AT91C_ID_TC1, 0};
Interface_t TC2_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TC2, AT91C_ID_TC2, 0};
Interface_t TWI_DEV     = {(struct PERIPH_BASE *)AT91C_BASE_TWI, AT91C_ID_TWI, 0};
...

unsigned char ConfigureDevice(Interface_t *Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger, u32_t IRQ_Mode, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){
    PMC_EnablePeripheral(Interface->ID);
    switch(Interface->ID){
    case AT91C_ID_FIQ:                                                      // Interface is FIQ!
        TRACE_ERROR("Attempt to Configure an FIQ as System Peripheral!");
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_SYS:                                                      // Interface is SYS!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_SYS)Interface->BASE)->AIC_IECR = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_PIOA|AT91C_ID_PIOB:                                       // Interface is PIO!
//      PIO_Configure();                                                    ///XXX: PIO_Configure To Be Modified
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_PIO)Interface->BASE)->PIO_IER= IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_SPI0|AT91C_ID_SPI1:                                       // Interface is SPI!
//      SPI_Configure(Interface, config, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK);         //XXX: SPI_Configure To Be Written
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_SPI)Interface->BASE)->SPI_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_US0|AT91C_ID_US1:                                         // Interface is USART!
        (AT91S_USART)Interface->BASE;
        USART_Configure(Interface->BASE, config, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK);
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_USART)Interface->BASE)->US_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        USART_SetTransmitterEnabled(Interface->BASE, 1);
        USART_SetReceiverEnabled(Interface->BASE, 1);
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_SSC:                                                      // Interface is SSC!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_SSC)Interface->BASE)->SSC_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_TWI:                                                      // Interface is TWI!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_TWI)Interface->BASE)->TWI_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
            TWI_ConfigureMaster(Interface->BASE, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK);
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_PWMC:                                                     // Interface is PWM!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_PWMC)Interface->BASE)->PWMC_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_UDP:                                                      // Interface is USB!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_UDP)Interface->BASE)->UDP_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_TC0|AT91C_ID_TC1|AT91C_ID_TC2:                            // Interface is TC!
        unsigned int div, tcclks;
        PMC_EnablePeripheral(Interface->ID);                                // Enable TC0 peripheral clock
        TC_FindMckDivisor(Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK, &div, &tcclks);         // Configure TC for a (u32_t Speed) In Hertz
        TC_Configure(Interface->BASE, tcclks | config);                         // interrupt configuration
        ((AT91S_TC)Interface->BASE)->TC_RC = (PERIPHERALS_CLOCK / (2 * div));
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_TC)Interface->BASE)->TC_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_CAN:                                                      // Interface is CAN!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_CAN)Interface->BASE)->CAN_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_EMAC:                                                     // Interface is EMAC!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_EMAC)Interface->BASE)->EMAC_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_ADC:                                                      // Interface is ADC!
        if (*Interface_irq_handler != NULL){
            ((AT91S_ADC)Interface->BASE)->ADC_IER = IRQ_Trigger;
        }
        break;

    case AT91C_ID_IRQ0|AT91C_ID_IRQ1:                                       // Interface is IRQ!
        TRACE_ERROR("Attempt to Configure an IRQ as System Peripheral!");
        break;

    default:
        TRACE_ERROR("Attempt to Configure an Undefined IRQ!");              // Unknown Interface!
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void ConfigureAIC(Interface_t *Interface, u32_t IRQ_Mode, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){
        AIC_ConfigureIT(Interface->ID, IRQ_Mode, *Interface_irq_handler);
        AIC_EnableIT(Interface->ID);
    }
```

I just pushed it to git: https://github.com/roosemberth/Coptex-Project/blob/2aa5d41e6f1b04e02589ec1eee1bc7d73c81ac2c/Scorpion-Source-Code/Interfaces_Configure.h

Comment: Is this the actual code? I can see a struct called interface_t and a parameter type of Interface_t

Comment: nope, the entire definition of the function is: `unsigned char ConfigureDevice(Interface_t Interface, u32_t config, u32_t Speed, u32_t IRQ_Trigger, u32_t IRQ_Mode, void (*Interface_irq_handler)(void)){`

Comment: What Mats just said. You code as posted doesn't show us what Interface_t actually is

Comment: "interface_t" instead of "Interface_t" was a typo, because while "patching" my code for the question (the four spaces) I did a mess

Comment: So, we need the definition of `USART_Configure` to understand what ERROR0 is referring to - it says that you are using the wrong type as argument, so without knowing what it SHOULD be, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Added!, the function takes a pointer to a usart control structure, and sets it up

Comment: So send it the BASE pointer in the struct, not the struct.

Comment: I tried USART_Configure(((AT91S_USART)Interface->BASE), config, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK); But I get `cast to union type from type not present in union` ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally your question said the function took

```
Interface_t * Interface
```

as the first parameter. Now you have changed it to

```
Interface_t Interface
```

If that really is the code, change all the lines using

```
Interface->
```

to

```
Interface.
```

And with a wild stab in the dark, the `USART_Configure` might want the base pointer:

```
USART_Configure(Interface.BASE, config, Speed, PERIPHERALS_CLOCK);
```

Comment: That's it!, Now I am getting the `cast to union type from type not present in union` Error inside the if statement, and the `passing argument 1 of 'USART_Configure' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]` warning in usart function

Comment: Parameteer 1 takes AT91S_USART, you sent it a BASE pointer. You could try asking another question if you can't figure it out - but make it small, relevant and concise.

Answer (score 2):

You have spelled `interface_t` with lower case `i` in one place and upper case `i` in another. C is a case-sensitive language, so you need to be consistent with the case (it's not uncommon to use upper-case initial for types).

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when posting the question; The correct is `typedef struct _Interface_t{
 struct PERIPH_BASE * BASE;
 u32_t ID;
 u32_t MODE;
} Interface_t;`

Comment: Are you sure now? Don't send us on another wild goose chase

Comment: Please put together a COMPLETE piece of code that can be compiled standalone, without any "we don't have this bit of code" - doing so will probably make you figure out what the problem is. Although doctorlove has made some good suggestions.

Comment: I posted almost all the code, as I'm starting, I didn't defined all ~120 Interfaces yet (If you read previous question, I will configure like 120 interfaces)

Comment: "a COMPLETE piece of code that can be compiled standalone" doesn't mean all the code. Sometimes if you pull the small bit that's giving you trouble into a different project and check it compiles before posting you might see the problem yourself :-)